# How to get Creditmemo ID from sales_order_creditmemo_refund?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, creditmemo

If I observe `sales_order_creditmemo_refund` event, there’s no entity_id or increment_id data in the passed object. I presume those are added before the `sales_order_creditmemo_safe_after` event. 
However, if I use the latter, it fires even if I add comments to a previously saved credit memo.

Is there a way to distinguish whether the event is triggered after a freshly refunded credit memo or anything else, or to get Id from the `_refund` event?

Checking for a state is not an option as orders can have multiple credit memos.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you have increment id of order?

Comment: I do have order_id, but orders have no creditmemo collections stored before the _refund event. Like HelgeB pointed out below, objects are only saved to the database shortly before the _save_after event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have an `entity_id` only after the object has been saved to database, therefore the earliest event to get that value is `sales_order_creditmemo_safe_after`.

But an `increment_id` can be generated in an earlier phase - you just have to generate it by yourself. Automatically the `increment_id` is generated in the save bevore process of the ressource model but only if there is no value for `increment_id`.

So one approach for you requirement can be to create the `increment_id` in your observer in `sales_order_creditmemo_refund` like this:

```
if (!$creditmemo->getIncrementId()){
    $entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode('creditmemo');
    $creditmemo->setIncrementId($entityType->fetchNewIncrementId($creditmemo->getStoreId()));
}
//from here you have an increment id
$creditmemo->getIncrementId();
```

You may also use `sales_order_creditmemo_safe_after` event and check if an `increment_id` or an `entity_id` has just been generated, by checking the `getOrigData` of the creditmemo. That may also work and you will fire the event only once for the newly generated  creditmemo:

```
if ($creditmemo->getOrigData('increment_id') == null){
  //creditmemo has just been generated and saved to database so you have increment_id and entity_id
  $creditmemo->getId();
  $creditmemo->getIncrementId();
}
```

You can try both approaches and see which one is the best for you - I would prefer the second varaint since you are sure the creditmemo has been generated and saved to database.

Comment: The second approach works really well.  Greatly appreciated!